# how to add multiple layout in horizontal scoll view at run time in android?

Tags: android, scrollview

I am developing an app in which I am receiving json objects in json array. Each json object contains one image and two string. Now I want to show each json object's data in `HorizontalScrollView` i.e. if there are 10 json objects then I have to show 10 layout(with one image and two textview) in `HorizontalScrollView`.

What I tried is that I created a layout with one `ImageView` and two `TextView` and inflated that layout in a view object. Now at runtime I added that view object in a `LinearLayout` (horizontal) which is in `HorizontalScrollView` to the length of json array but it's giving me an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Can anybody tell me solution for this.

Here is my code

```
Linear layout ll_hori_scroll = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.ll_hori_scroll);//layout in horizontal scroll view 
View v = View.inflate(_activity, R.layout.list_item_recentlyadd_home, null);//custom layout 
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
ll_hori_scroll.addView(v); 
}
```

and its give error in `ll_hori_scroll.addView(v);`

Answer (score 1):

Scrollview will allow only one child, so you have to add child layouts to child of of ScrollView.

Like this

```
<ScrollView
   <LinearLayout

      /// you can add layout's here at dynamic

   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: here is my scroll view
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_hori_scroll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
    
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

Comment: Linear layout ll_hori_scroll = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.ll_hori_scroll);//layout in horizontal scroll view
  
  View v = View.inflate(_activity, R.layout.list_item_recentlyadd_home, null);//custom layout
  
  
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   ll_hori_scroll.addView(v);
  }

Comment: Can you post your code and log cat clearly in Question. and tell me where is the error line also.

Answer (score 0):

addView must add "indepent object", you just add the same "list_item_recentlyadd_home" into ll_hori_scroll twice...

The code should be below:

```
Linear layout ll_hori_scroll = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.ll_hori_scroll);//layout in horizontal scroll view 

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    //move below line from outside into for loop
    View v = View.inflate(_activity, R.layout.list_item_recentlyadd_home, null);
    ll_hori_scroll.addView(v); 

    //if you wants to use this view later, you can add the tag for your view
    v.setTag(i);  // v.getTag() can get their position
}
```

Hope it helps you... ^^